# Determine whether this compound propositions is satisfiable (¬p∨¬q∨r)∧(¬p∨q∨¬s)∧(p∨¬q∨¬s) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ q ∨ ¬r) ∧ (p ∨¬r ∨ ¬s)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine whether this compound propositions is satisfiable   (¬p∨¬q∨r)∧(¬p∨q∨¬s)∧(p∨¬q∨¬s) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ q ∨ ¬r) ∧ (p ∨¬r ∨ ¬s)

Please show step by step solution

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $$(\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r) \land (p \lor q \lor \lnot r)$$

Comment: This question seems not to meet the [standards for the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards